# Trying to show that $R/M$ simple implies that $M$ is maximal. Subquestion: Can non-unit elements make ideals?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I want to show that for $M\triangleleft R$.

$M$ is maximal $\iff$ $R/M$ is simple.

---

So first I made some observations:

$\begin{matrix}M\textrm{ is maximal } & & R/M \textrm{ is simple}\\\Updownarrow&&\\R/M\textrm{ is a field}\end{matrix}$

---

So firstly if $M$ is maximal, $R/M$ is a field, and if a unit element, $u$, gets into an ideal $I$, then since $rI\subseteq I, \quad\forall r\in R$, $r=u^{-1}$ means that $uu^{-1}\in I$ and then $1\in I$ meaning that $I=R$. If there are no unit elements in an ideal $I$, then $M=\{0\}$ since $R/M$ is a field. So any ideal in a field is $\{0\}$ or $R$ itself. Which means that $R/M$ being a field, means $R/M$ is simple.

---

$\begin{matrix}M\textrm{ is maximal } & & R/M \textrm{ is simple}\\\Updownarrow&\large{\nearrow}\!\!\!\!\!\!\large{\nearrow}&\\R/M\textrm{ is a field}\end{matrix}$

---

So we need now only get one arrow coming back from $R/M$ simple. This is what I am having trouble with. Some thoughts, perhaps the fact that $R/M$ is simple, and hence has no nontrivial ideals, means that we have no non-unit elements, hence is a field.

Is it possible to always make a new ideal somehow using nonunit elements?

Comment: For the subquestion: If you have a non-unit $r \in R$, then the set $rR = \{rq\mid q \in R\}$ cannot be the whole ring (for instance, by definition of non-unit, it cannot contain $1$). It is, however, an ideal. It is additively closed ($rq + rq' = r(q+q')$ for all $q, q' \in R$), and it is closed under multiplication by all of $R$ ($(rq)\cdot q' = r\cdot (qq')$, again for all $q, q' \in R$), which is what defines an ideal. It's called the ideal _generated by_ $r$, and s usually written $(r)$.

Comment: $M/R$ Was a typo of  $R/M$ In these two diagrams, right? @algebra

Comment: For a concrete example, the zero ideal is maximal in $M_2(\Bbb R)$, but the quotient is not a field (or division ring, either.)

Comment: As for your subquestion "can nonunit elements make ideals" the answer is yes, of course. Every element can be used to generate an ideal. It looks a bit different depending on the commutativity of e ring, but either way yes.

Comment: @rschwieb Yes a typo once and then copy any paste, sorry. Thanks for your comments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $M$ is maximal, $R/M$ is not necessarily a field. This is true when $R$ is commutative and has an identity. In fact, if $R$ is not commutative, then $R/M$ might not even be a division ring (the non-commutative version of a field).

**Theorem.**
*For any ideal $M$ in a ring $R$, there is a bijection between the set of ideals of $R$ which contain $M$ and the set of ideals of $R/M$, given by $I \mapsto I/M$.*

So if $M$ is maximal, the only ideals of $R$ which contain $M$ are $R$ and $M$, which implies the only ideals of $R/M$ are $R/M$ and $M/M = \{M\}$ (the trivial ideal). Hence $R/M$ is simple.

Conversely, if $R/M$ is simple, its only ideals are $\{M\} = M/M$ and $R/M$, so the only ideals of $R$ containing $M$ are $R$ and $M$. Hence $M$ is maximal.

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question.